# Selenium 2.50 not working on firefox 45

Tags: selenium, firefox

I am getting error as while using firefox with webdriver.

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Firefox version:45.0
Selenium:2.50.1
Windows 10 64 bit

Is anyone getting the similar issue or any idea what is the solution for this.Its working fine with chrome but with firefox none of the URL's are getting loaded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=port%207055%20after%2045000%20ms

Comment: I have even tried selenium 2.53,still getting the same result.Can anyone provide a solution or how to downgrade Firefox??

Comment: I have tried all the ways as mentioned in the link.Still its not working for me.Can anyone here provide how to use  selenium 2.51/2.53 with firefox 45.0 on windows 10??

Answer (score 6):

Update to selenium server 2.53 solves the problem. http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: unfortunately not solved. This version not support firefox... I hope yet not support. we have to wait for next subversion

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728659/6469532

**Summary:** Combination of **Firefox 47.0.1** and Selenium **2.53.1** will resolve the issue as of now.

Comment: I can confirm that a combination of Firefox 47.0.1 and Selenium 2.53.1 work indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Previously I had same issue, can't loaded the url using Firefox version 45.0.1. The external JAR's is selenium-java-2.46.0. After upgrade the selenium server to selenium-java-2.53.0 (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and update the other external JAR's in the project (some JAR are updated and removed in selenium version 53). Finally, I can loaded the URL successfully on Firefox 45.0.1 using selenium-java-2.53.0.

Comment: For me it's just not working...and there seems no solution as I have tried many ways but same result...

Comment: Selenium-java-2.46.0 contain 33 items in libs folder, i remove these items and replaced it with 11 new items in libs folder of selenium-java-2.53.0. I also replaced selenium-java-2.46.0.jar and selenium-java-2.46.0-srcs.jar with selenium-java-2.53.0.jar and selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar. You can update it by right click on your project -> Properties -> Java build path, go to Libraries tab. Hope this can work for you.

Comment: So u mean that there should be only selenium 2.53 jars for Java and rest should be removed?

Comment: No, I mean all jar files from the extract zip file selenium 2.53 in (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) should be provided in the project

Comment: I have added all the jars from lib folder of selenium 2.53.Still same result for me.

Comment: @dheerajkateja I'm having the same issue with 2.5.3 and every FF version. Were you ever able to get around this?

Comment: No bro,there is no solution it seems.I have tried many ways but no luck

Comment: @dheerajkateja I installed maven via brew, how about you?

Comment: Maven is in built in eclipse...this is a different issue.How come maven came in between all this

Comment: just trying to figure out what is different about my environment. I have colleagues with pretty much same setup and it works for them

Comment: @dheerajkateja I got mine working -- I was by default targeting Java 1.8 in the Runtime JRE. Installing 1.7 and specifying that allowed FF to work

Answer (score 1):

This combinations are working for me -

Firefox 45.0.1 + Selenium 2.53.1 
Firefox 45.0.2 + Selenium 2.53.1
Firefox 47.0.1 + Selenium 2.53.1

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.0'
```

the above entry in the gemfile worked for me with Firefox 45.0.1 and ruby 2.0.0-p647.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded Firefox to version 43 and it seems to solve the problem. 
Conclusion (..?) selenium 2.53 does not support Firefox 45.

I hope this helps

Comment: I have tried with Firefox 43 as well.Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to firefox 44.0.2 and it worked for me. 
To downgrade:
1. Unistall firefox 45.0.1
2. Unistall Mozilla Maintenance Service

Install:
1. firefox 44.0.2 I found it on: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Comment: Its not oworking with 44.0.2 either.May i knw which selenium version you using with FF 44.0.2??

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 45 doesn't support selenium driver still. Firefox 44.0.2 is fine to deal with selenium, so go with it and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

it was Firefox upgrade issue, Selenium 47 is not compatible with Firefox 44 and up.

I had to downgrade all the way to 39.

Answer (score 0):

Try using firefox 46.0.1. It best matches with Selenium 2.53
Surely it will work for you.

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/win64/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

For RSpec and RubyMine users:

If your RSpec or Ruby tests are not talking to the browser, but the browser is opening and doing nothing this is likely because your selenium-webdriver is not up-to-date with the current browser.

Or this can be because there are multiple versions of the selenium-webdriver gem installed and it is using the oldest one by default.

Here you can see the multiple versions listed in RubyMine:

File > Preferences > Language & Frameworks > Ruby SDK & Gems

[image: RubyMine preferences > Language & Frameworks > Ruby SDK & Gems]

Go to terminal and then your project root where your gemfile is stored and type:

```
gem list
```

You will get a list with a line like the following:

*selenium-webdriver (2.53.4, 2.44.0)*

You can uninstall the old version using something like the following:

```
gem uninstall /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@stillwell selenium-webdriver
```

Note: you can get the path by running `gem environment`

Then it will ask you the following:

*Select gem to uninstall:*

1. *selenium-webdriver-2.44.0*
2. *selenium-webdriver-2.53.4*
3. *All versions*

If you don't have the version you need, to install a specific version run the following at the terminal prompt:

```
gem search selenium | grep webdriver
```

You should see something like the following:

*selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)*

Then you can install that specific version with the following in the terminal:

```
gem install selenium-webdriver -v 2.53.4
```

I also updated my FireFox browser.

I am using Capybara and RSpec. Generally, Capybara defaults to FireFox but if you are still having problems you may want to explicitly define the driver at the top of your .rb script.

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
 profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
 profile['browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone'] = 'ignore'
 profile['startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional'] = 'about:blank'
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end
```