# socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer Selenium-python

Tags: python, sockets, selenium

I am new to selenium and trying an exampler http://www.marinamele.com/selenium-tutorial-web-scraping-with-selenium-and-python">here

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "q")))
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.NAME, "btnK")))
        box.send_keys(query)
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

I have installed selenium using

```
pip install selenium
```

But Its not working.

Error showing up is

```
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

and sometimes

```
raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Firefox open up and then shuts down saying "Firefox has quit unexpectedly"

I have gone through [Selenium headless browser webdriver [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328060/selenium-headless-browser-webdriver-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer?rq=1) and [Why am I getting this error in python ? (httplib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767934/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-python-httplib) but nothing helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade your firefox and try again.Looks like all versions of firefox not compatible with selenium.

Reference:[Selenium 2.50 not working on firefox 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063908/selenium-2-50-not-working-on-firefox-45)

Comment: Any news on this? I've Selenium 2.53.1 and firefox 47.0 . same error

Answer (score 2):

It sounds obvious, but in opposition to the existing answer I want to add a reminder to try *upgrading* your Selenium, Firefox & geckodriver instances.

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue before I remembered to try a simple update, which resolved the problem.

--

Update Selenium in Python with

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

Check geckodriver version

```
geckodriver --version
```

Install latest [gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)