# Selenium WebDriver for Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have few problems with Selenium WebDriver .
I'm using the lates firefox edition (47.0) and tied to use the last Selenium-Server-standalone-2.53.0.jar but when I used this version with the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

firefox can not open I get the message that there is a problem and I can debbug firefox.

when I try with the selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar the firefox window dose open but it is not blank and doesn't go to the side that I want e.g driver.get("https://www.google.com");

and I get the following error :

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 2.53 doesn't support Firefox 47. Here is more information:
[Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

You have to downgrade your Firefox to 46 version. Remeber to disable automatic updates.