# Error using Selenium Webdriver and FireFox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

"The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

I am using

Selenium version 2.53.6

firefox version 47.0

ubuntu 14.04.4

python 3.4.3

Here is the code that I am using

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https:\\aweber.com')

browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

Comment: Firefox version 47 has issues with Selenium WebDriver (see the very bottom [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/47.0/releasenotes/)), try using an earlier version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer to this link.
[Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

You can find a solution to your problem in the above link or you can just simply downgrade your Firefox to version 45.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Selenium WebDriver 2.53.6 is not compatible with Firefox 47.0.

I had the same problem and I download the Firefox (version 45) and everything works perfectly. Try this version : https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0/