# Selenium with Marionette on Windows: "Permission Denied"

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

After updating to Firefox 47 and installing Marionette (instructions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)  my code is throwing the following error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#firefox requires a new webdriver code-named marionette
#Selenium must be told to use said driver (not necessary in the future)
caps= DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps["marionette"]=True
#STABLE RELESE NOT SUPPORTED USE DEV EDITION
caps['binary']="C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\" 
driver=webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
driver=webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities) 
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: permission
denied
```

I have added Marionette to my `PATH`, renamed as wires, and tried pointing selenium directly to the `.exe` file with no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply downgrade your Firefox to version 45 as Firefox 47 is not compatible yet.

Or

You may refer to this link.
[Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

You can find a solution to your problem in the above link.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: UPDATE

from:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47 Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 has been released on 30th June 2016. FirefoxDriver is working again with Firefox 47.0.1 as browser.

Comment: I was actually having issues because I wasn't using double backslashes  on this line `caps['binary']="C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\"` but regardless your answer led me to upgrade selenium and fix the issue

Comment: I tried to run your program and found this error, but thought it was a typo while writing question details.