# Selenium WebDriver upgrade results in UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I recently found that my Selenium Java libraries were not working. Version 2.48.2 would open a Firefox window and then "stall" with no error within Netbeans nor Firefox itself before returning from `new FirefoxDriver()`. I figured that this version of Selenium might be broken so I found the latest Java libraries (Version 2.53.1) and have been trying to get them to work.

My issue now is almost the same but with two errors. The first is thrown by Netbeans when trying to execute `new FirefoxDriver()`.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'MrComputer', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
...
```

The second is from Firefox itself. The window opens but instantly encounters the error.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: firefox.exe
  Application Version:  47.0.0.5999
...
```

The code I am using is quite simple. Just the line

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I am by no means an extremely knowledgeable Selenium user so I am not sure what other information I could provide that might be of help.

**EDIT:** It seems that my Firefox version was not high enough to use the 2.53.1 Selenium libraries. My version of `47.0.0.5999` needed to be at least `47.0.1`.

Prior to this, version 2.53.0 did need to make use of the `MarionetteDriver` as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728659/2985796).

> Unfortunately Selenium WebDriver 2.53.0 is not compatible with Firefox
>   47.0. The WebDriver component which handles Firefox browsers (FirefoxDriver) will be discontinued. As of version 3.0, Selenium
>   WebDriver will have MarionetteDriver as the default running
>   implementation for Firefox tests.
>
> ...
>
> UPDATE
>
> Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 has been released on 30th June 2016.
>   FirefoxDriver is working again with Firefox 47.0.1 as browser.

Comment: If your firefox verison `47` you need to use `MarionetteDriver`.. have a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Comment: Excuse me if this sounds snarky, but I cannot find a single mention on that page or the parent page of it that mentions that I must use `MarionetteDriver`, do you have any "proof" that I must use it over `FirefoxDriver`?

Comment: I also take it you imported the correct firefox driver library?

Comment: I might have not, could you explain what you mean by Firefox driver library? I assume this is the Selenium jar file? (I don't have the exact name in front of me) Something like `selenium-java-2-53-1.jar`? Along with the server jar file `selenium-server-java-2-53-1.jar`?

Comment: Have you tried to find out the solution on google regarding this... there are many exampls that proofs it to use `MarionetteDriver`... even i`m using also..:)

Comment: I always go to google first. // Could you provide a link to the proof, I cant seem to find anything on it.// EDIT: Ahh I found something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47

Comment: At the end of the first answer in the link I posted there is the update "Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 has been released on 30th June 2016. FirefoxDriver is working again with Firefox 47.0.1 as browser." // From what I can tell `MarionetteDriver` is not needed at this point.

Comment: So from what I can now gather, from the link I posted in the comment above and my error message in the OP. I need to upgrade my FF version from `47.0.0.5999` to at least `47.0.1`. I will try this when I have time later and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Selenium 2.53.1 the Firefox version needs to be at least `47.0.1`. Updating my Firefox did the trick.

EDIT: It also seems that version 47.+ was not released to the Ubuntu archives for a few weeks after the Windows version.