# selenium 2.53.1 isnot working for firefox 47.0.1

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, windows-10

I am getting an error while using

- windows 10
- selenium 2.53.1
- Firefox 47.0.1

I tried using selenium 2.53 with Firefox 46.0.1 as well as 46.0, where I cannot open any URL but can launch Firefox browser.

The error I'm getting is:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>    to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Comment: Only solution i see is to Down Grade Firefox versions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Answer (score 0):

you can use marionette driver which i recently used. You need to download and rename it to wires. you can download from the following link
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
below is the code you need to write.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Marionette for firefox\\wires.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdgc21jJHOAhVCvY8KHZ4aCdcQPAgD");
    System.out.println("marionette working fine....");
```