# Selenium Python 3.0.0b2 not compatible with latest Firefox released version 48.0

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

**QUESTION:** Is there a list of Firefox versions that are Selenium-compatible maintained online?

How do I know if an update will break some functionalities (other than testing and discovering that my scripts are not running :-) )? The latest version of Selenium for Python is not properly working with the latest released Firefox (48.0), so I had to downgrade to Firefox 47.0.1 in order to get my scripts working again.

The error I got is the "famous" one below:

"The browser appears to have exited " selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Advice: "Please wait before to update your Firefox version"

The driver.get() function for Firefox is not working - it opens a blank page and does not load the one I ask to load.

Comment: Probably the same problem described (and answered) in [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47).

Comment: Hi @RoadieRich this is something else. From Firefox 48 Marionette should be taken into use. (Easily saying Marionette is a MOZILLA's Gecko engine)

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your original question, I don't believe there is a list of versions that are compatible. However, in reference to Firefox 48 in particular, [from the mouth of David Burns of Mozilla](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2110): "When Extension Signing ships in Firefox 48 or later the current Selenium WebDriver addon approach will no longer work and you will need to update to Marionette."

If you want to use Firefox 48 rather than downgrading, you can learn about setting up Marionette [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette).

Comment: Thanks Sam, I found the same. So somehow Mozilla wants to use their developed Marionette :-) I pushed your answer +1 although it looks like nobody maintains a list of proper working versions. Thanks again and I wish you a nice day.