# Selenium 2.53 or 2.48 not working in Firefox 48.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-ide

I am getting an error in Firefox 48.0 in new the update from firefox 47

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
> Firefox console output: 066   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with
> changes to installed add-ons

My system and browser configuration are:

> Firefox 48
>
> Selenium 2.48 also try 2.53
>
> Window 8 64bit

I also tried the marionette driver but did not receive proper output with that.

Any ideas on how to fix this besides downgrading firefox?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858

Comment: Same problem here, selenium must be fixed :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Comment: @BoniGarcía - but if you use seleniun 2.48 with Firefox 47 then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution for my question with Firefox 48 and Selenium 3.0.0(Beta 3) because Selenium 2.48 didn't work.

If you want run selenium script then you have to download....

> Selenium 3.0.0(Beta 3) - http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
>
> GeckoDriver exe - http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

```
put below code in your script

public class FirefoxTest{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Path + geckodriver.exe");
    //For E.g ("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://geckodriver.exe")

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Older versions of Selenium (like 2.5.x) do not work and won't work with Firefox 48+.
The reason is that Firefox 48 changed a lot of stuff, including the fact that extensions must be signed by Mozilla to work with Firefox. 
To fix the Selenium issue, Mozilla took ownership of `FirefoxDriver()` and they a released a Marionette version for this, including a Gecko driver.

This is what you need to use to be able to execute your tests on Firefox 48+.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend downloading firefox 46 which seems to be the best match for selenium 2.53.x.

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/win64/en-US/

Once I downgraded to firefox 46.0.1 everything was working as expected.