# Java: Cannot enable Selenium 2.53 with firefox 48

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I followed this topic: [Selenium 2.53 or 2.48 not working in Firefox 48.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930370/selenium-2-53-or-2-48-not-working-in-firefox-48-0)

There has been an answer that suggested: [Selenium using Java - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858)

So I downloaded gecko drivers and tried to enable Marionette. This is my function that creates FireroxDriver with correct Gecko driver path set:

```
private WebDriver createFirefoxDriver() {
  final String ver = "0.10.0";
  final String tmp = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
  final String sys = tmp.contains("win") ? "win" : tmp;
  final String bit = System.getProperty("os.arch").replaceAll("\\D+","");
  final String geckoPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/gecko/geckodriver-v" + ver + "-" + sys + bit;
  final String geckoExec = geckoPath + "/" + ("win".compareTo(sys) == 0 ? "geckodriver.exe" : "geckodriver");

  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoExec);
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
}
```

Then I call:

```
WebDriver driver = createFirefoxDriver();
```

My gecko driver path is correctly set. However, i still receive an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
me: Recursive scan of loop@mozilla.org
1471095430100   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"   {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"JydGd8wvA9R0","location":"app-  global","version":"48.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","upd ateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1470478892000,"updateDate":1470478892000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":5022,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1471095430100   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1471095430101   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471095430102   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1471095430102   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1471095430104   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1471095430105   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1471095430106   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1471095430108   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1471095430131   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1471095430137   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1471095430137   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1471095430356   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1471095430534   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1471095430535   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471095430539   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471095430577   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430577   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430578   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430582   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471095430582   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1471095430594   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471095430616   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
at cz.trit.prof.worker.createFirefoxDriver(SearchWorker.java:187)
at cz.trit.prof.worker.SearchWorker.<init>(SearchWorker.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at cz.trit.prof.worker.WorkerFactory.createWorker(WorkerFactory.java:29)
at cz.trit.prof.WorkOrchestrator.registerWorker(WorkOrchestrator.java:60)
at cz.trit.prof.LinkProfilerCore.registerAgentWorkers(LinkProfilerCore.java:116)
at cz.trit.prof.LinkProfilerCore.start(LinkProfilerCore.java:79)
at cz.trit.prof.ui.console.AgentConsoleMain.main(AgentConsoleMain.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Exception in thread "main" cz.trit.prof.worker.WorkerCreationException: Error during initialization of new worker instance.
at cz.trit.prof.worker.WorkerFactory.createWorker(WorkerFactory.java:38)
at cz.trit.prof.WorkOrchestrator.registerWorker(WorkOrchestrator.java:60)
at cz.trit.prof.LinkProfilerCore.registerAgentWorkers(LinkProfilerCore.java:116)
at cz.trit.prof.LinkProfilerCore.start(LinkProfilerCore.java:79)
at cz.trit.prof.ui.console.AgentConsoleMain.main(AgentConsoleMain.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at cz.trit.prof.worker.WorkerFactory.createWorker(WorkerFactory.java:29)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
me: Recursive scan of loop@mozilla.org
1471095430100   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"JydGd8wvA9R0","location":"app-global","version":"48.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1470478892000,"updateDate":1470478892000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":5022,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1471095430100   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1471095430101   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471095430102   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1471095430102   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1471095430104   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1471095430105   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1471095430106   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1471095430108   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1471095430131   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1471095430137   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1471095430137   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1471095430356   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1471095430534   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1471095430535   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471095430539   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471095430577   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430577   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430578   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430582   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471095430582   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1471095430594   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471095430616   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'lenovo', ip: '192.168.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.7.0-1-ARCH', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:125)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
at cz.trit.prof.worker.SearchWorker.createFirefoxDriver(SearchWorker.java:187)
at cz.trit.prof.worker.SearchWorker.<init>(SearchWorker.java:55)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
me: Recursive scan of loop@mozilla.org
1471095430100   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"JydGd8wvA9R0","location":"app-global","version":"48.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1470478892000,"updateDate":1470478892000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":5022,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1471095430100   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1471095430101   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471095430102   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1471095430102   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1471095430104   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1471095430105   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1471095430106   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1471095430107   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1471095430108   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1471095430130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1471095430131   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1471095430137   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1471095430137   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1471095430138   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1471095430356   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1471095430364   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1471095430534   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1471095430535   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471095430539   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471095430577   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430577   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430578   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471095430582   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471095430582   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1471095430594   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471095430616   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
... 21 more
```

Comment: Please share the output of `geckoExec` variable for all platform...

Comment: This is output: /home/user/public_html/testapp/gecko/geckodriver-v0.10.0-linux64/geckodriver, where /home/user/public_html/testapp is path of my app

Comment: Ok once try with hard coded path as : `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user/public_html/testapp/gecko/geckodriver-v0.10.0-linux64/geckodriver");` and let me know..:)

Comment: Thank you, the problem remains. However, I've realized that even if i run "./geckodriver -b /usr/bin/firefox" from console, nothing happens - application launches and stucks. Just /usr/bin/firefox works. I also tried compile geckodriver from sources and I've experienced same problem.

Comment: Ok try once as :- `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user/public_html/testapp/gecko/geckodriver-v0.10.0-linux64/geckodriver");‌​WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();` and let me know

Comment: Forget once `FirefoxDriver` and try with `MarionetteDriver`...

Comment: I had similar problem with MarionetteDriver. I decided to switch to ChromeDriver for a while and perform test there. Thank you for helping me Saurabh.