# Python selenium "about:blank&utm_content=firstrun" error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've being trying so hard to figure out what's going on with my code, but I couldn't help.
Whenever I run my program I got this error in the picture bellow.
I'm using python 3.4.4 and selenium last version of it.

Windows 10

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6hSz.png)

Comment: What is `profile`? Also versions of selenium/firefox?

Comment: selenium-2.53.6, Firefox 48.0. <br> "profile line" that line unneeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what your FF version is, I assume it's one of the latest. Anyways you need to use FF below 47 or time to switch to MarionetteDriver

here is some useful information [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I downgrade my Firefox Mozilla and It's work just fine.