# Python Selenium Webdriver.Firefox() hangs at 'about:blank&utm_content=firstrun'

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Am using Selenium version 2.53.6 and have tried it with Firefox 44,45,46 and 47...

Whenever I run the line

> driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Firefox initializes but hangs at 'about:blank&utm_content=firstrun' and I cannot type additional code on the command line.

Been researching on how to solve this and so far the only available solution that did not work for me was to downgrade FF (but I have tried numerous older versions already) (am using Python 2.7 and have also tried and failed using 3.5)

Comment: I've seen this same issue calling the FirefoxDriver from C# with the latest stable version of everything, Selenium 2.53.1 and FireFox 48.0.2.

Comment: This might help you. [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Comment: Possible dupliate of [Python selenium “about:blank&utm_content=firstrun” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056722/python-selenium-aboutblankutm-content-firstrun-error)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using chrome. http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_win32.zip Download that and extract it to your `python27/scripts` folder located in the root directory in the `C:\\ Drive` and then run this script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

And It should connect you to google.com Hope I helped. :)

Comment: Hi! Would like to try out chromedriver but am getting this error: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH."

Comment: try the script exactly as I have it this is python 2.7 btw

Comment: jovin.pizarro I believe the chromedriver executable (Firefox is the only browser that doesn't require a separate executable file) needs to be in the path of your python app. I really like the selected answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Comment: @ElderSmash you are correct. Putting the chromedriver.exe into your \Python\Scripts\ folder will fix @jovin.pizarro's issue. However, I get a new problem when I'm running the Chrome browser, instead of the issue stated above, it gives: `data:, ` in the URL field of the newly opened Chrome browser. So for me, this once again did not work @thesonyman101