# Protractor fails in Firefox and IE browsers

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have hard time getting the protractor to run tests in Firefox

Following is a sample test case. It can be tested in Chrome - but fails in Firefox and IE browsers.

### Test file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>automation test</title>
        <style>
            #tst{
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div id="tst"></div>
        <button id="clickme">Click me</button>        
        <script>

            document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                document.getElementById('tst').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Specs file(indexspecs.js)

```
describe('sample test', function(){

    it('change bgColor to red when click the button', function(){
        browser.driver.get("http://localhost/test/index.html");
        var btn = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('clickme'));
        var clRed = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
        btn.click();

        expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.id('tst')).getCssValue('background-color')).toEqual(clRed);
    });
});
```

### Protractor config file

```
exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    specs: ['indexspecs.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
    },

    capabilities: {
//        'browserName': 'internet explorer'
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    }
};
```

**protractor version - 2.0.0**
**Firefox version - 45**
**IE version - 11**

When set to Firefox, the browser launches - but not getting the url to run the test.

Comment: There has been some outage on firefox versions working with protractor, have you had a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too generic to pinpoint the rootcause. But I will try to answer all common issues that might have caused your problem

1. Update to new version of Protractor (use `npm update protractor`) - you are using 2.0.0 which is pretty old (`protractor --version` to check it after update). I am using 3.3.0. There is even more latest version - [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor)
   I just tried your spec and its all working fine with FF-45
2. Coming to IE, I am not sure if you have the IE driver already, if not run the below command

   ```
   webdriver-manager update --ie
   ```

Your script might fail in IE as it will throw a warning that 'Active X methods would be blocked' and may be you have to set the ignore option in IE settings before you run

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start a standalone Selenium Server locally. You can look at here;

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js

Your config file should be like this;

```
exports.config = {

    seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server...',

    specs: ['indexspecs.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
        defaultTimeoutInterval:30000
    },

    capabilities: {
        //'browserName': 'internet explorer'
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    }
};
```

You can download jar file from here

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/