# Use most recent browser version with JMeter Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Im trying to use JMeter with the Selenium WebDriver plugin to do some testing. I know that it requires Firefox v. 26, however I find this to be pretty useless given that testing on anything besides the most recent browser version is pointless, as that is what users will be using.

Using the current WebDriver plugin with Firefox v 50 results in the 'browser.get()' not working. Is there a way to get the plugin to work with Firefox 50?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Answer (score 1):

1. The latest [Selenium/WebDriver Support plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) available via [JMeter Plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) as of now is version 1.4.0. It comes with selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0

   [image: WebDriver Firefox]

   It means any browser supported by Selenium 2.52.0 will be supported
2. Looking into [Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) Selenium 2.52.0 supports Firefox 45 which is an ESR release according to [Mozilla FAQ](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/):

   [image: Mozilla Faq]

I don't know where did you get the information regarding Firefox 26, I would recommend upgrading to Firefox 45 which should be supported till June 2017 and hopefully JMeter Plugins maintainers will upgrade Selenium libraries to version 3 by that time.

In general WebDriver will be always behind the browsers development so you will have to live with the supported versions.

References:

- [JMeter Plugins Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)