# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 while executing code using GeckoDriver and Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Code Trials :

```
public class loginmethod { 

    @Test 
    public void login() throws InterruptedException { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Tools\\geckodriver"); 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Binary Version Details :

- FireFox : 60.0
- Selenium Jar : 2.45
- GeckoDriver : 20.1

When I run code using Firefox driver following error is given:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v=
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1526302485156   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database 
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on QA\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5274473150250365422webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping activity-stream@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping followonsearch@mozilla.com to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\followonsearch@mozilla.com.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping formautofill@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\formautofill@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping onboarding@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\onboarding@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping screenshots@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on activity-stream@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on aushelper@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com in app-system-defaults
1526302485236   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on onboarding@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1526302485238   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1526302485238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1526302485238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {}
1526302485332   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1526302485332   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1526302485336   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[C0][GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v= (t=6.22361) [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v=
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[C0][GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v= (t=2.67818) [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v=
```

Comment: give us clarity about your question for answers

Comment: place your code here for better understanding

Comment: I run this but it gives an error
public class loginmethod {
 
 @Test
 public void login() throws InterruptedException {
   
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Tools\\geckodriver");
  
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: u need to keep geckodriver.exe in path

Comment: i correct this error still same error displayed org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console

Comment: Can you update selenium Jar as well as gecko driver ?

Comment: your FF version please ?

Comment: FF : 60 , jar : 2.45 , geckodriver : 20.1

Comment: refer to  this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47/37728659#37728659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v=
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
```

...implies that the GeckoDriver was unable to initiate/spawn a new Web Client session/instance successfully.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.45** which is almost **2.5 years** older.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is **v20.1**.
- Release Notes of **0.19.0 (2017-09-16)** clearly mentions the following :

> Note that with geckodriver 0.19.0 the following versions are recommended:
>
> - **Firefox 55.0 (and greater)**
> - **Selenium 3.5 (and greater)**

- Release Notes of **0.16.0 (2017-04-21)** clearly mentions the following :

> Note that geckodriver v0.16.0 is only compatible with **Selenium 3.4** and greater.

- Your *Firefox* version is **v60.0**.

So there is a clear mismatch between **Selenium Client v2.45**, **GeckoDriver v20.1** and **Firefox v60.0**.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v60.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. I resolved my issue. Now it is perfectly running